# Does Redux Saga select return mutable state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga, saga

Does Redux Saga `select` return a mutable or immutable state?

See https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga

Comment: You should always view state as immutable when working with redux. Saga doesn't cast your state to an immutable data structure or anything specifically, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `select` operator just uses the Redux store's `getState()` method internally.  So, the return value from the selector function is probably going to correspond to the contents of the store state tree.

Redux itself does not actually stop you from mutating your state.  It *wants* you to handle state immutably, but the base library does not enforce that in any way.

As a result, if your store state tree is composed of plain JS objects, then yes, the return value from `select` is almost definitely going to be mutable.  If your store state tree use made up of something like Immutable.js Maps and Lists, then the return value from `select` will probably be immutable.